# How to instantiate Python list without syntactic sugar

Tags: python, object, instantiation, syntactic-sugar

I want to explain object instantiation in Python to some students. They have been coding for a couple of sessions. Now, I'd like to reveal them that they have been working with objects all along. For example, the floats, ints, booleans, lists they have been using are all objects.

Now I want them to show how to instantiate objects. I'd like to show them by using the objects they are already familiar with (e.g., lists). But, is there any way to instantiate an empty list very explicitly, e.g. `myList = List()`?

I'm only familiar with syntactic sugar approaches, such as

```
myList = []
```

or using the built-in function

```
myList = list()
```

Can it be done using the regular instantiation syntax?

Comment: Does a 3rd way really exist?

Comment: @aa333 You could try this: `import sys; type(sys.argv)()`

Comment: `list()` is what you are looking for. If there is any difference between classes and types, I don't know it.

Comment: There are quite a few "functions" that are often used as such but are really just types. Even `int` is actually a type and not a function that convert things in `int`s. It's pretty easy to proove: `isinstance(0, int)` or `isinstance([], list)`. If `int` or `list` were really functions than `isinstance` would raise an error because it requires a type(s) as second argument.

Comment: This may be explicit enough: `type([]) is list`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Despite the fact that `list` is writen without the cappital "L", it IS a type in Python. So, when you do the `l = list()`, you're not calling any built-in function or syntatic suggar, you're instantiating the type list.

The uncapitalized "L" of the `list`, is the same as the "D" in `dict`. It's because both are [Built-In Types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html).

Comment: See `type(print)` and `type(list)` to observe the difference.

Comment: I see. So, why is it listed under 'Built-in Functions'? 'Built-in-classes' makes much more sense. Then the lack of capitalization adds to my confusion.

Comment: If you got confused about this, then the best aprouch to teach this particular part is showing custom types (classes), and after that, present the Built-In Types as exceptions. But that's just how I would like to learn.

Comment: @pansen: I suspect the documentation categories are historical. It used to be (prior to Python 2.2, I think) that builtin types were notably different than regular types. They were constructed by regular functions, rather than their names being their types. There are still some very minor differences (for instance, you can't add arbitrary class variables to the `list` type), but in most usage these days, builtin types are just like user-defined types.